# How to clear API cache in react native app programmatically

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

I have question about cache clear in react native app with programming. Currently I have working on e-commerce app. Here I am using more more 100 API calls (different functionalities) for all screens. I got to know from a search engine reg every API call can take up to 35MB from RAM.

I had written some logic to reduce API calls by using local async storage and should component update method call for each screens. As of now API calls are reduced but after usage of 15 to 20 mins app is getting laggy.

So that I am searching for clearing the cache in app for every 15 or 20 mins programmatically in app, but could not find any solutions. Please can  anyone help me out for this question?

API call I am using in code following:

```
fetch('https:...URL')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      return responseJson;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
```

Platform-> React native

Above fetch I had written more than 100 places for all screens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a header `Cache-Control` like this:

```
return fetch(url, {
  headers: {
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Expires': 0
  }
}).then(function (res) {
  return res.json();
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.warn('Request Failed: ', error);
});
```